# Changing the fragment on button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

I am having fragments with some buttons i.e. next & previous. Whenever button is clicked, I need to move on to the next fragment. Actually I implemented this with ViewPager, so when user swipes it move on to next fragment. But how can I change the fragment just by clicking the buttons. Please note that, buttons are present in Fragment class not in FragmentActivity class.

Comment: Take a look at the FragmentManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) and the FragmentTransaction (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Answer (score 1):

If button is part of the fragment, then your parent activity shall implement interface your fragments would also understand. Then, when button is hit, it shall tell the parent activity about that and it shall replace the fragment. If button is part of activity layout then read about managing fragments with Fragment Manager and its transactions.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class FragmentWithButtons extends Fragment {

    public interface Callbacks {
        void nextFragment();
        void previousFragment();
    }

    private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
        void nextFragment() {
            // ignore
        }
        void previousFragment() {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

    private Button mPrevBtn;
    private Button mNextBtn;

    private View.OnClickListener mPrevBtnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallbacks.previousFragment();
        }
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mNextBtnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallbacks.nextFragment();
        }
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity: " + activity + " must implement " + Callbacks.getCanonicalName());
        }
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    public void onDetach() {
       super.onDetach();
       mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    }
} 

public class ActivityWithButtonFragment extends Activity implements FragmentWithButtons.Callbacks {
    @Override
    public void previousFragment() {
        // switch to previous fragment using FragmentManager...
    }

    @Override
    public void nextFragment() {
        // switch to next fragment using FragmentManager...
    }
}
```

Also, check out http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

That should give you an idea how to make the fragment-activity communication happen.